# React-Native Images Displayed in iOS Simulator but are not Displayed on iPhone Device

Tags: ios, react-native

We are building a react-native app and have ran the app in an Xcode simulator and the png images load, but when we bundle the ipa and run the app on a real device, the images do not appear.

We have our images in an images.xcassets file, with @2x and @3x images as well, with the correct naming (e.g. abc@2x.png)

I have seen other people with this issue, and the solution for them has been to check the case of their image files, that are bundled in the ipa, and make sure they match the case of the images in the code. I have done this and still have the issue.

I have attached screenshots, displaying the content of our images.xcassets file, the use of the images in our code, the bundle resources section in Xcode, the page in the simulator where the images load and the page on a device, where the images fail to load.

This is the first question I have ever posted on stack overflow, so if there is anything else I could provide then please let me know.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

[Use of Images in Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeTmt.png)

[Images.xcassets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPruh.png)

[Images that are referenced in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9WcU.png)

[Xcode Bundle Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6wTo.png)

[Xcode Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGaRo.png)

[iPhone Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIfnh.png)

[New ipa Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Fnc.png)

[New Xcode Bundle Resources for PNG files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl0T1.jpg)

Comment: You don‘t habe to add the images in Xcode you can although store them in a react native asset folder.

Did you take a look into the created ipa file?

Comment: @MichaelBahl Thanks for your response. We have tried adding the images to a react native asset folder and add that folder to the "Bundle Resources" section in XCode, but the issue still arises. The suggestion to look at the contents of the ipa file was helpful. It confirmed that the images were not being added to the ipa. I decided to add each individual image to the Bundle Resources section of XCode. I checked the contents of the newly generated ipa, the images have been added to the ipa, however I still cannot see the images on the device. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: I have added screenshots of both, the contents of the newly generated ipa and the Xcode Bundle Resources section with the PNG files added.

Comment: Did you try require() instead if import?

Comment: @JordanBurge I am also facing this issue, Did you get the success?, Can you help me here.